# Prove the the transformation of basis vectors is a basis for the image of T?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $T: V \to W$ is a linear transformation and $\{v1, v2, v3\}$ is an ordered basis for $V$. Prove that $\{T(v1), T(v2), T(v3)\}$ is a basis for the image of $T$.

Can someone help please?

Comment: This is not true - the image vectors only span the image. They form a basis iff T is injective

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It needn't necessarily be a basis, for example if $\dim\bigl(\operatorname{im}(T)\bigr)<3$ then $\operatorname{span}\bigl\{T(v_1),T(v_2),T(v_3)\bigr\}$ is not a basis of $\operatorname{im}(T)$.

Answer (score 0):

In general what is true is that  $\{T(v1), T(v2), T(v3)\}$ spans the image of $T$ and thus contains a basis for $Im(T)$.

It’s a basis if and only if dim(W)=dim(V)=rank(T).